# Add Firebase Token to Angular $HTTP header

Tags: angularjs, http, firebase, http-headers, firebase-authentication

So I want to add a firebase token to all http requests.  I am using the angularJS 1.X framework.

I have an interceptor function which normally I would just add it like this:

```
    .factory('Interceptor', function () {

  interceptorFactory.request = function (config) {
    config.token = firebaseToken;

    return config;
  };

  return interceptorFactory;
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interceptor');
});
```

But the issue is the only way to get the firebase token is through a promise, so for that I would need to do something like this:

```
.factory('Interceptor', function () {

  interceptorFactory.request = function (config) {

    getFirebaseToken().then(function(token){
    config.token = token;
    return config;
    });
      };

  return interceptorFactory;
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interceptor');
});
```

The problem though, is because the token is retrieved Asyncronously, the factory interceptor does not wait for promise to resolve, so the request is sent without the token.  If anyone knows how to get around this that would be help full.

Also, I know I could just get the token before I make every http request but then that would cause a lot of duplicate code, and I can't get the token on application startup and just store it cause it has an expiration.

Comment: In the [documentation for the $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage), `token` is not described as a property of the `config` object. The `$http` service is just going to ignore it anyway.

Comment: The [documentation for $http intercepters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) clearly states that the function needs to return the config object directly, **or a promise containing the config or a new config object.** Simply return a promise **[chained](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)** from the async call to get a token.